# parsing php value into ignited datatables

Tags: php, datatables

Hopefully there're others who's been using ignited datatables *crossing fingers* ... I've been trying this for a while and it makes no sense why it doesn't let me use a PHP value at all -->

```
include $DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/include/config.inc';
include $DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/include/session_check.inc';

require_once($DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/include/Datatables.php');
$datatables = new Datatables();

// MYSQL configuration
$config = array(
'username' => $dbuser,
'password' => $dbpass,
'database' => $dbname,
'hostname' => $dbhost);

$datatables->connect($config);

$datatables
->select('users.id as user_id, users.name as realname, users.username as username, users.email as email, users.phone as phone, domain.name as domain_name')
->from('users')
->join('domain', 'domain.id = users.domain_id', 'left')
->where('users.domain_id = "$domain_id"')
->add_column('available', '$1', 'available(available)')
->add_column('edit', '<a href="/wh.php?edit=1&id=$1" title="Purge the info for this Stock"><img src="/images/icons/dark/pencil.png" border="0"></a>', 'stock_id')
->unset_column('user_id');

echo $datatables->generate();
```

Now, the value $domain_id isn't at all available. I wonder did I put it wrongly or it's just acceptable in such string composition?

Answer (score 0):

Okay .. my mistake .. instead of the line

```
->where('users.domain_id = "$domain_id"')
```

I should've used this

```
->where('users.domain_id', $domain_id)
```

it's running all fine now .. thanx anyway :-)